# Return Statement inside of a Function ( Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, return

I was trying some Javascript exercices, and one of them ask to define a function max() that takes two numbers as arguments and returns the largest of them. we need to Use the if..else statement. That's the code that i've tried :

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
function max(x, y) {
if(x>y)
{
return x;
}
else
{
return y;
}
}
</script>
<button onclick="max(5, 7)">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that it didn't work. I've thought about changing the return x and the return y with alert ( alert(x) and alert(y) ) and it worked, so the problem must be in the return.  I just can't figure out why it didn't work since the beginning ! :/

Comment: do you know what does return do??

Comment: Please add more detail about what you're trying to do. Your function does appear to find the max of two values, but you're not using the return value.

Can you give a better description of how you want to use the max value?

Comment: Please define "it didn't work". What you expect your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: It should probably be noted that javascript already has this function, `Math.max(5, 7)`

Comment: (And please use indents, I just Stopped Caring.)

Answer (score 3):

You are just returning the value, you are not doing anything with it.  Perhaps you want something like:

```
<button onclick="alert(max(5, 7));">Click me</button>
```

A basic JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D6XSv/

Answer (score 3):

it does work, you just don't do anything with the return value

you call the max method, and then you get the higher value (in your example 7) back and just throw it away

Answer (score 1):

No your function works, but you don't do anything with the return value. Try this:

```
<button onclick="alert(max(5, 7))">Click me</button>
```